# Python program throwing error when called through subprocess

Tags: python

I have a simple python file `myfile.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def on_message(ws, message):
    if message == 'pong':
       pong = True
       receiver_exists = True

def on_error(ws, error):
    print("### error ###", error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print('### connected ###')
   

if __name__ == "__main__":

import websocket
import _thread as thread
import time
import re
from camera import VideoCamera
from deviceSpecificVals import machineSerial, token
    while True:
        try:
            uri = f"ws://myurl/stream/{machineSerial}/?{token}"
            ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(uri,
                              on_open = on_open,
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)

            ws.run_forever()
        except:
            pass
```

When I run this by simply executing it from the terminal it works as expected.
When I try to run this from another python program using:
`os.system('myfile.py')`
or
`subprocess.Popen(['myfile.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

Both will throw the error `ImportError: No module named websocket`

Why does it work fine from terminal but not using os.system or subprocess

Comment: do you run it in terminal - `myfile.py` or `python myfile.py`? Do you have other Pythons installed? Do you have this problem when you run `/usr/bin/python myfile.py`? Maybe it runs  with other Python. maybe you should use different shebang in code - ie `#!/usr/bin/python3` ? You could add code which display information about used Python, current working dictionary, etc.

Comment: Change this to answer and I will mark it as such. 
The shebang (python3) did it, good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes computers may have two (or more) Pythons installed (especially Linux/Unix) and it may need correct shebang to run it with expected version

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

To run also with version installed in virtual environment

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python3
```